# Netlogo: compare a variable of a turtle in two different moments in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am writing simulation in Netlogo, and I need to compare variable`s value (of a specific turtle ) in two different moments t and (t-1),Can you give me a suggestion please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the lagged value (e.g., in a turtle attribute).  For example,

```
turtles-own [x xlag]

to setup
  ca
  crt 1 [set x random-float 1.0]
end

to go
  ask turtles [set xlag x]  
  ask turtles [set x random-float 1.0]
  ask turtle 0 [show x - xlag]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alan : Thanks for your suggestion, I'm not sure I understand your answer, Well I try  to model the firm`s decision to recruit or not a number of employee; Here is a code I have made using your suggestion :

```
firms-own [ 
  number-emplyed-now  number-employed-previously
  salary-offers
  ]

households-own[
  desired-salary]

to setup
  create-firms 1
  set [ number-emplyed-now floor( turnover / salary-offers) ]
end

to go
  ask firms [ set number-employed-previously number-emplyed-now ]
  ask firms [ set number-emplyed-now floor( turnover / salary-offers)]
  ask firms [
    If number-emplyed-previously < number-employed-now
    [ask households with desired-salary < salary-offers 
      n-of (number-employed-now - number-emplyed-previously)
      set color red ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: yes, this is what Alan meant - an extra variable to hold the previous value. you have a couple of problems here though (1) you need `clear-all` at the beginning of setup, `reset-ticks` at the end of setup and `tick` at the end of go. If you don't understand why, I would recommend you do the NetLogo tutorial again to understand the passage of time. (2) you can combine your `ask firms` in the go procedure into a single ask firms` (3) your third `ask firms` means that every firm that satisfies your condition will ask all the relevant households - is this what you want? (4) your `n-of` should...

Comment: ... be before the agentset that it is sampling from. (5) you will need to use `myself` for the household to access the firm's variable values